# Небольшая помощь по регулярному веражению

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть перемменная

```
$test = "floppuspasibozapomosh";
```

Как сделать проверку, если в этой перемменой есть floppu то делать одно а иначе другое

Comment: а зачем регулярка? [`strpos($test, 'floppu')`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php) и готово. Если очень уж регулярку хочется, то просто [`preg_match('/floppu/', $test)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$test = "floppuspasibozapomosh";

if(strpos($test, 'floppu') !== false)
    echo 'yes';
else
    echo 'no';
```

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос закрит.

Comment: @Анатолий, в таком случае следует принять ответ галочкой слева от вопроса.

Comment: Пишет что могу принять ответ через 1 минуту